# Azure Machine Learning Studio - Import from Cosmos Db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently trying to connect to a DocumentDb (MongoDb) using Azure Machine Learning Studio.

I am currently following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/import-from-cosmos-db) guide, however it seems out of date already. The assumptions I have taken have lead me to get an `Error 1000: ... DocumentDb client threw an exception` `The underlying connection was closed. The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

The guide, and Azure Machine Learning Studio, outline the following parameters to make a connection.

Endpoint URL, Database ID, DocumentDb Key, Collection ID. It also tells you to look under the `Keys` blade to find these, which does not exist anymore.

These are the assumptions I have taken;

- Endpoint URL = host + port under the Connection String blade. `https://host.com:port/`
- Database ID = the database name listed under the Data Explorer blade.
- DocumentDb Key = Primary Password under the Connection String blade.
- Collection ID = the name of a collection in the db from the Data Explorer blade.

I have, for now, also opened all connections to the database just to make sure I wasn't closing the network to outside requests which, I guess, means that at least the DocumentDb key is a poor assumption.

---

After some input from Jon, below, here is the current state of things

- Endpoint URL = the Uri from the Overview blade.
- Database ID = the database name listed under the Data Explorer blade.
- DocumentDb Key = the Primary Password under the Connection String blade.
- Collection ID = the name of a collection in the db from the Data Explorer blade.
- Sql query = `select top 10 * from CollectionID`
- Sql parameters = {}

Comment: Maybe try using the URI in the "Overview" blade as the Endpoint URL?

Comment: @Jon Looks like that progressed it somewhat. The error I am getting now is `Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system.`.

Comment: Hmmmes, maybe double check your database and collection IDs match what you have in CosmosDB?

Comment: @Jon if the Id's are just the name of the database / collection I want to get data from they are 100% correct. I'm not sure what the DocumentDb Key is supposed if it is not supposed to be the primary password.

Comment: What SQL query are you using with it?

Comment: @Jon `select * from collectionId` so if the collection I was referencing was called `products` it would be `select * from products`

Comment: Dang, that's what I have on mine, too :/ Sorry I'm not sure what could be causing the other error

Comment: @Jon Were my assumptions correct? Other than the Endpoint URL, which I corrected from your suggestion. I'm guessing you used the Primary Password for the DocumentDb Key?

Comment: Yep, those are the same properties I used in mine

Comment: @Jon The effort is appreciated! Thanks Jon.

Comment: @Jon Ok, strange. I just tried again and it seems to have imported the data. You should make an answer so that I can mark it as correct. Do you know the best way to add machine learning studio to the firewall of cosmos db?

Comment: Oh, glad it was able to import! :p I didn't have to update the firewall, though it did cross my mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through discussion in the comments, it may be that the "Endpoint URL" just needed to be updated, but I'll go over all of the inputs in case anyone else needs a reference to it.

- Endpoint URL - Can use the URI in the CosmosDB "Overview" pane in the Azure Portal
- Database ID - The name of the database to connect to
- DocumentDB Key - The primary password from the "Connection Strings" pane in the Azure Portal
- Collection ID - The name of the collection to read data from

And, for reference, here's what my data explorer looks like in CosmosDB (database ID then collection ID):

[image]

And the settings in Azure ML Studio to import the data:
[image]